# Best algorithm for strings match coefficient

Tags: .net, algorithm, optimization, string-matching

I am working now on my lab - search using Simulated Annealing and the function that estimates states can be expressed in an array of symbols as (**"-1"** means a black ball on the board, **"0"** - gap on the board, **"1"** - a white ball on the board). Initially balls located like this: **"-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1"** and the goal state is **"1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1"**. I need to know the algorithm that gives a coefficient of how close each successive state to the goal state. It will be used in the Simulated Annealing processing to select the best state. I saw many of them - Lowenstein distance, Djakar index and etc. How do you think which matches best to my case?

Comment: This depends on your definition of "close". Which rules are there for mutating the state? What are the costs?

Comment: Suppose, cost is 0 for each move operation. I only need to know something like "ordinal hash" of the sequence, so I could compare them.

Comment: Cost 0 is kind of suspicious since in that case any string can be mutated to any other with a zero cost - making any distance useless.